# No suitable constructor found error while linking to array

Tags: java, arrays, oop

the code is:

`Person aTrainee = new Trainee (firstName,lastName,streetAddress,postCode,phoneNumb,performanceAverage,trainingArea);`

and the error says

```
no suitable constructor found for Trainee...ectect
```

Person is an array

Trainee is an item in the array (one of three, trainee, employee and management)

If I remove the items in the brackets then I do not get the error, but without it, the code does not work.
I have made sure that the items in the brackets match up with the rest of the code 10+ times, I have spent over 1 hour trying to figure this out, I would love ANY advice you can give me.

edit:
this is the code, there is A LOT of it so here is the important part.

```
else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(toTrainee))
       {

           Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
           Scanner choice = new Scanner (System.in);
           System.out.println("To select a Trainee to edit, enter a value from 0 to 3: \n");
           int selection = choice.nextInt();

               if(selection <= 8)
               {
                   System.out.println("Incorrect, please enter a valid number!");
                   sc.nextLine();
                   break;
                }

            System.out.println("Please enter a first name for the Trainee \n");
            String firstName = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter a Last name for the Trainee \n");
            String lastName = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter a Street Address for the Trainee: \n");
            String streetAddress = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter a Post code for the Trainee: \n");
            int postCode = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter a Phone Number for the Trianee: \n");
            String phoneNumb = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter a performance average for the Trainee: \n");
            String performanceAverage = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter a Training area for the Trainee: \n");
            String trainingArea = in.nextLine();

            Person aTrainee = new Trainee (firstName,lastName,streetAddress,postCode,phoneNumb,performanceAverage,trainingArea);
            System.out.println(aTrainee);
            myWorker.set(selection,aTrainee);

        }
```

Trainee constructor

```
public class Trainee extends Person
{
    private String performanceAverage, trainingArea;
    public Trainee()
    {
       super();
       performanceAverage = "";
       trainingArea = "";
    }
    public Trainee(String myFirstName, String myLastName, String myStreetAddress, int myPostCode, int myPhoneNumb, String myPerformanceAverage, String myTrainingArea)
    {
        super(myFirstName,myLastName,myStreetAddress,myPhoneNumb,myPostCode);
        performanceAverage = myPerformanceAverage;
        trainingArea = myTrainingArea;
    }

    public void setPerformanceAverage(String myPerformanceAverage)
    {
    this.performanceAverage = myPerformanceAverage;
    }

    public void setTrainingArea(String myTrainingArea)
    {
    this.trainingArea = myTrainingArea;
    }

     public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + ", Performance Average is " + performanceAverage + ", and Training Analysis is  " + trainingArea;
    }
}
```

This is Person which gives Trainee a few more things like Name ect.

```
public class Person
{ 
       private String firstName;
       private String lastName;
       private String streetAddress;
       private int postCode;
       private int phoneNumb;

       public Person()
       {
           firstName = lastName = streetAddress = "";
           postCode = phoneNumb = 0;
       }

       public Person(String myFirstName, String myLastName, String myStreetAddress, int myPostCode, int myPhoneNumb)
       {
           firstName = myFirstName;
           lastName = myLastName;
           streetAddress = myStreetAddress;
           postCode = myPostCode;
           phoneNumb = myPhoneNumb;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String myFirstName)
        {
            this.firstName = myFirstName;
        }

        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String myLastName)
        {
            this.lastName = myLastName;
        }

        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setStreetAdress(String myStreetAddress)
        {
        this.streetAddress = myStreetAddress;
        }

        public String getStreetAdress()
        {
        return streetAddress;
        }

        public void setPostCode(int myPostCode)
        {
        this.postCode = myPostCode;
        }

        public int getPostCode()
        {
        return postCode;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumb(int myPhoneNumb)
        {
        this.phoneNumb = myPhoneNumb;
        }

        public int getPhoneNumb()
        {
        return phoneNumb;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
             return "This person's information is: " + firstName + " " + lastName + ", " + " " + streetAddress + " " + postCode + ", phone number is  " + phoneNumb;
        }
}
```

and this is the array (note the first line is just a test so ignore the entries)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ShopMan
{
  public static void main()
  {
     ArrayList<Person>myWorker = new ArrayList<Person>();
     Person aShopEmployee = new ShopEmployee("Yazz","Hasan","1/43", 4215, 55271095, "Timber", 010101001, 50000);
     myWorker.add(aShopEmployee);
     aShopEmployee = new ShopEmployee("","","",00,00,"",00,00);
      myWorker.add(aShopEmployee);
     aShopEmployee = new ShopEmployee("","","",00,00,"",00,00);
      myWorker.add(aShopEmployee);
     aShopEmployee = new ShopEmployee("","","",00,00,"",00,00);

     Person aManagement = new Management("","","",00,00,"",00,00,false);
     myWorker.add(aManagement);
     aManagement = new Management("","","",00,00,"",00,00,false);
     myWorker.add(aManagement);
     aManagement = new Management("","","",00,00,"",00,00,false);
     myWorker.add(aManagement);

     Person aTrainee = new Trainee("", "", "", 00, 00, "", "");
     myWorker.add(aTrainee);
     aTrainee = new Trainee("", "", "", 00, 00, "", "");
     myWorker.add(aTrainee);
     aTrainee = new Trainee("", "", "", 00, 00, "", "");
     myWorker.add(aTrainee);
     aTrainee = new Trainee("", "", "", 00, 00, "", "");
     myWorker.add(aTrainee);
     aTrainee = new Trainee("", "", "", 00, 00, "", "");
     myWorker.add(aTrainee);
     aTrainee = new Trainee("", "", "", 00, 00, "", "");
     myWorker.add(aTrainee);
     aTrainee = new Trainee("", "", "", 00, 00, "", "");
     myWorker.add(aTrainee);

     for (int i=0; i < myWorker.size(); i++)
     {
        System.out.println(myWorker.get(i));
     }

     while (true)
     {
         Menu.main(myWorker);
     }
  }
}
```

ANSWER FOUND!

```
String phoneNumb = in.nextLine();
```

needed to be

```
int phoneNumb = in.nextInt();
                in.nextLine();
```

Thank you so much to
Russell Zahniser
and creinig
and everyone else

Comment: No one can help you unless you provide code (the constructor definition). Also, please add a language tag.

Comment: We need to see the definitions of Person and Trainee. Already, it looks a little odd because `new Trainee` would generate a trainee object, but you're assigning it to an object which represents an array of objects, at least based upon how you describe them.

Comment: Do you have any constructor for Trainee that takes 7 Strings?

Comment: yes, but its 5 strings and 2 int

Comment: There's still a bug in your `Trainee` constructor: `super(myFirstName,myLastName,myStreetAddress,myPhoneNumb,myPostCode);` You'll need to swap the last two parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the type of the `phoneNumb` parameter.

Comment: It's int like it needs to be everywhere, cant be that.

Comment: But what type is the `phoneNumb` variable that you are passing for that parameter?

Comment: I dont get what you are asking, sorry, why do you thin its the phoneNumb anyways?

Comment: @Yazz: Because you define `phoneNumb`as String, but the Trainee constructor expects it to be an int.

Comment: I think I see what you are talking about, let me try it